# Acces Preferences From another class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have an application which has a Prefernces Class and I want to know how could i make so that when  the application is started the settings to be applied even before entering the preferences ( settings ) class. I have a getPrefs() void method which is called when i press "Save" Button in preference activity.

So, could you help me and tell what should I do the "default" preferences to be applied when entering the application ? (I need getprefs method from another class )

I would be grate if you could give me some advices or tips.Thank you !

Comment: Also, if you are talking about `SharedPreferences`, the beauty of them that you can reach them (the latest instance) from anywhere within the application's scope using `PreferenceManager` of the proper getter of the `Context` instance - in case you know it's name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an instance of the `SharedPreferences` from anywhere in your application use:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPrefences(context);
```

To set a value in the preferences, you need to call the editor for those preferences, then set the value for a key and finally commit the result. It can all be done in a single line:

```
prefs.edit().putString("myKey","myValue").commit();
```

This would store the string value `myValue` on a key named `myKey` and it will be accessible (after you commit) to any class if it has the application's context when it calls `getDefaultSharedPreferences`.

To retrieve the stored value you specify the key and a *fallback* value in case there is no preference set with that key:

```
prefs.getString("myKey","oops no value found");
```

Comment: @blackcrow Caught me in a good mood, I'm usually the angry mob type :P

Comment: another +1 for being a nice guy, I would not have done the same

Comment: @thisMayhem 22 min and he has not accepted your answer as well. No.

Comment: @blackcrow, You are right my friend. Downvote tomorrow from me too!

Comment: neat answer, +1. You were being fair and thorough, so +1 for your comment too ;)

Comment: @rekaszeru, he even accepted the answer, so I don't have to feel bad